# Windows 10 keeps deleting stuff I have NOT selected

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

If I have a `.html` file and a folder linked to it, selecting the html file also deletes the folder.

I just want to delete the html file and leave the folder.

Is there a way to make Windows work normally so I can delete what I actually want to be deleted?

Comment: So just confirm.  If you select the .html the folder is deleted?  What happens to the .html file?

Comment: it deletes the folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurs because of the Connected Files feature implemented in Windows 2000.

To disable this 'feature', use Registry Editor to view the following registry key, and then add the following value to this key, or modify it if the value already exists:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer 

Value: NoFileFolderConnection
Value Type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

NOTE: This value is normally not defined, and file connection is enabled by default. A value of 1 disables file connection.

[ [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252721?wa=wsignin1.0) ]

Answer (score 4):

You have a saved web page (when you save a page as `Webpage, Complete`) with its pictures and other files saved in the corresponding folder. Deleting that html file deletes the folder -- This is the default behavior.

One way to delete the html file without deleting the folder is to rename the folder to something else first.

Another way is to delete the html file in a command prompt.